# Aggregating in R per ID but keeping the ID repetitions

Tags: r

If I have the table

```
ID  1 1 1 2 2
N.  3 2 1 1 1
```

I want to get the same number of rows but with a new column that would be the mean of N per ID.

Ie

```
ID            1. 1 1 2 2
N.            3  2 1 1 1
Mean(N)       2  2 2 1 1
```

How to do that in R?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yet another way:

```
df
  ID N
1  1 3
2  1 2
3  1 1
4  2 1
5  2 1

df$Mean <- rep(aggregate(N~ID, df, mean)[,2], table(df$ID))

df
  ID N Mean
1  1 3    2
2  1 2    2
3  1 1    2
4  2 1    1
5  2 1    1
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `ave`.  By default, the `FUN` is `mean`, so we don't need to specify it.

```
df1$Mean <- with(df1, ave(N, ID))
```